# How to take screenshot of all pages irrespective of the fact that the test case is passing or failing?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have written a code to take screenshot of a page in selenium webdriver.But I want to take screenshot on every page as the control progresses from one page to next page irrespective of the fact that the test case is passing or failing. As the work on 1 page gets completed i need a screenshot. Can anyone help me?

```
package com.training.edureka.selenium.module7;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class screenshotOfAllCases {

    WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeTest
    public void openBrowser() throws InterruptedException
    {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com");


    }

    @Test

    public void getScreenshot()
    {
        try {
        File scrFile =
                ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new
                File("e:\\homepage.png"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    @AfterTest

    public void closeBrowser()

    {
                driver.close();

    }
                }
```

Comment: Your test takes a screenshot when running the test for that specific page. What you need to do is respond to changes via an [event listener](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html)

Comment: Try the code Mentioned,. you can call function where you want

Comment: Why - vote Please mention the reason

Comment: @iamsankalp89 I did mention the reason. You deleted your answer so quick, you didn't read the comment I posted under it. Should still be there. Also, should only ask "Why was my post downvoted" on *your* post, or no one will know what you're talking about.

Comment: As you mention, I have to learn testng once I will learn it , then I will try to give answers of TestNG tag. Thanks for help:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153932/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-vince-emigh).

Answer (score 0):

try following code 
public class ScreenshotUtils implements IInvokedMethodListener {

```
@Override
public void beforeInvocation(final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult) {
if (method.isTestMethod()) {
  //Open browser
 }
}

@Override
public void afterInvocation(final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
       //Logic to your screenshot taking 
      //Close browser
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I see using Junit in import org.junit.Test, try Junit Rule in base Test class:

```
@Rule
  public TestRule testWatcher = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, Description test) {
      getScreenshot()

    @Override
    public void succeeded(Description test) {
      getScreenshot()
    }
  };
```